# Google reCAPTCHA never let me add comment

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've already been using google recaptcha on few websites, every time I've verified data the same way, but now the verification doesn't work. I mean, it does, but it never let me add comment, it always thinks I am a robot. Am I using something wrong? But I didn't change anything from previous website...

Here is the code, thank you for advices!

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          header ("Location: /diskuse?e=3");
        }
        $secretKey = "my-secret-key";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          header ("Location: /diskuse?e=4");
        } else {
// add comment to database
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($responseKeys);`?

Comment: @KoenHollander so, when I checked reCAPTCHA, `var_dump($responseKeys);` is `NULL`. When I didn't check it, value is "Please check the the captcha form."

Comment: Is `var_dump($response);` also `NULL` ?

Comment: @KoenHollander no, it's `bool(false)`

Comment: Alright, now we know that the file_get_contents fails. But why? Can you visit the URL in your own browser? (Enter some fake information, to test it)

Comment: @KoenHollander ok I've visited URL google.com/recaptcha/etc.... with my keys and it threw me this response:
{
  "success": false,
  "challenge_ts": "2017-04-20T09:34:43Z",
  "hostname": "sazkamagazin.cz"
}

Comment: Can you try to echo this on your site: `echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");`

Comment: @KoenHollander didn't write anything...

Comment: I guess var_dump equals to false?

Comment: You also can try to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php instead.

Comment: @KoenHollander same problem with curl_init() either..

Comment: Can you share your cURL example?

Comment: @KoenHollander
`$response=curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);

        $rr = curl_exec($response);
        
$responseKeys = json_decode($rr,true);`

Comment: @KoenHollander actually with the code I pasted here, it threw me this: { "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2017-04-20T10:00:22Z", "hostname": "sazkamagazin.cz" }

Comment: That, looks like an succes :)
But did you recieve that on your browser or in cURL?

Comment: @KoenHollander Well I tried to add comment and file add.php showed me this, instead of redirect or something...

Comment: Maybe this is your solution. Can you retry to implement it in your form?

Comment: @KoenHollander well but still I just always get this message, comment is not added to database and no redirect or anything happens. And it takes soooo long before the message is showed.
well you can try it: www.sazkamagazin.cz/diskuse

Comment: Maybe your query does'nt work?

Comment: @KoenHollander it does, when I remove captcha verification, comments are added.